# Ajax PHP: Variable from page url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

With the following AJAX call I set pagination for a webpage. It works.

In my PHP file already have:

```
$page= $_POST[page];
```

AJAX call:

```
function pg2(page) {
    pag.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: { page: page },
        success: function(ccc) {
            pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
        }
    });
}
```

I also need to pass `id` from the URL.

```
http://website.com/title/?id=2 **//I need to pass id in php file and echo it out.
```

How can I do that? many thanks.

Comment: Use `$_GET[]` or `$_REQUEST[]`;

Comment: If it's passed in the URL use `$_GET['id']` to retrieve it.

Comment: You can also use .get{} method to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?> // like this you can store php variable in javascript varibale
```

Now call **function pg2(page,id)** however you want...

```
  function pg2(page, id) {
   pag.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "file.php",
   data: { page: page, id: id },
   success: function(ccc) {
    pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
   }
  });
 }
```

hope it may help you

Answer (score 1):

If your JS is embedded:

```
function pg2(page) {
    var id = <?php echo intval($_GET['id']); ?>;
    pag.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: { page: page, id: id },
        success: function(ccc) {
            pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
        }
    });
}
```

If your JS is in an external file (best option):

```
var id = <?php echo intval($_GET['id']); ?>;
pg2(page, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read id via GET and pass in the function

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

function pg2(page, id) {
pag.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: { page: page, id: id },
    success: function(ccc) {
        pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
    }
});
}
```